# Define different \printacronyms template from acro package

Tags: tables, acro, translate

I need following format for my acronyms table:

[image]

But currently with MWE I have this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to re align my acronyms in three columns so that first comes the short form, than long foreign form and than the long local form.

I have tried working with `DeclareAcroListStyle` but I simply can't figure it out.

Here is the MWE:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\DeclareAcronym{atm}{
    short = ATM,
    long = asinkroni način prijenosa,
    foreign = Asynchronous Transfer Mode,
    foreign-lang = english
}
\DeclareAcronym{isdn}{
    short = ISDN,
    long = digitalna mreža integriranih usluga,
    foreign = Integrated Services Digital Network,
    foreign-lang = english
}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah \acs{atm}, blah blah blah \acs{isdn}

\printacronyms


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way.

Table cells form groups which is why we need a redefinition of an `acro` command. (I will update `acro` so the next release will work without redefinition.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english,croatian]{babel}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_get_foreign:n #1
  {
    \prop_if_in:NnT \l__acro_foreign_prop {#1}
      {
        \tl_use:N \l__acro_foreign_sep_tl
        \prop_get:NnN \l__acro_foreign_prop {#1} \l__acro_foreign_tl
        \group_begin:
          \tl_use:N \l__acro_foreign_list_format_tl
          {
            \acro_foreign_language:VV
              \l__acro_foreign_lang_tl
              \l__acro_foreign_tl
          }
        \group_end:
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareAcroListStyle{custom}{table}{
  table = longtabu ,
  table-spec = @{}lXX@{} ,
  foreign-sep = &
}
\acsetup{
  list-style = custom ,
  list-long-format = \itshape ,
  list-foreign-format = 
}

\DeclareAcronym{atm}{
    short = ATM,
    long = asinkroni način prijenosa,
    foreign = Asynchronous Transfer Mode,
    foreign-lang = english
}
\DeclareAcronym{isdn}{
    short = ISDN,
    long = digitalna mreža integriranih usluga,
    foreign = Integrated Services Digital Network,
    foreign-lang = english 
}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah \acs{atm}, blah blah blah \acs{isdn}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: with XeLaTeX do not use the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages but use  `fontspec` instead.

---

Switching foreign with “native” descriptions takes a bit more effort:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english,croatian]{babel}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_get_foreign:n #1
  {
    \prop_if_in:NnT \l__acro_foreign_prop {#1}
      {
        % \tl_use:N \l__acro_foreign_sep_tl
        \prop_get:NnN \l__acro_foreign_prop {#1} \l__acro_foreign_tl
        \group_begin:
          \tl_use:N \l__acro_foreign_list_format_tl
          {
            \acro_foreign_language:VV
              \l__acro_foreign_lang_tl
              \l__acro_foreign_tl
          }
        \group_end:
      }
  }

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__acro_list_entry_long:n #1
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l__acro_foreign_bool
      { \acro_get_foreign:n {#1} }
    \tl_use:N \l__acro_foreign_sep_tl
    \group_begin:
      \bool_if:NT \l__acro_capitalize_list_bool
        { \bool_set_true:N \l__acro_first_upper_bool }
      \acro_write_long:Vf \l__acro_list_long_format_tl
        {
          \prop_if_in:NnTF \l__acro_list_prop {#1}
            { \__acro_get_property:nn {list} {#1} }
            { \__acro_get_property:nn {long} {#1} }
        }
    \group_end:
    \acro_cite_if:nn { \l__acro_citation_all_bool } {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareAcroListStyle{custom}{table}{
  table = longtabu ,
  table-spec = @{}lXX@{} ,
  foreign-sep = &
}
\acsetup{
  list-style = custom ,
  list-long-format = \itshape ,
  list-foreign-format = 
}

\DeclareAcronym{atm}{
    short = ATM,
    long = asinkroni način prijenosa,
    foreign = Asynchronous Transfer Mode,
    foreign-lang = english
}
\DeclareAcronym{isdn}{
    short = ISDN,
    long = digitalna mreža integriranih usluga,
    foreign = Integrated Services Digital Network,
    foreign-lang = english 
}
\DeclareAcronym{foo}{
  short = foo ,
  long = foo-long
}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah \acs{atm}, blah blah blah \acs{isdn}, \ac{foo}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I must say I'm having a hard time grasping how all these latex packages work. You are a saver :D

Comment: May I just ask how you knew how to do that, because I didn't see any of that in the `acro` documentation? I'm new to latex and it's kind of overwhelming.

Comment: Also, is it possible to switch places of foreign and native descriptions? From what I understand you are modifying piece of code that is used to output foreign word in a list, but not the row it self?

Comment: @Reygoch I am the author of `acro` so I better should know… :)

Comment: Oh, wow :D didn't expect I'd get answer from you. Very nice and thought out package by the way.